# Present AppStore Payment Sheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, subscription, storekit

I have an app with auto-renewable subscriptions, and when user tap on subscription i call:

```
SKProduct *product = ...;
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

`StoreKit` presenting `Alert` where asking user if he/she wont to buy a subscription, but in few other applications i saw native `view`(seems to be native), and i also want to present such `view` in my app. **What kind of `view` is it?** Thank you!

### [image: native app store ui]

**UPD:** I've fount that this view is calling "**Payment Sheet**", and found that this sheet exist in Apple Pay SDK, but not in Store Kit, how this can be presented at all? :)

Comment: I think its `SKProductViewController` where you set the `SKProduct` to be your recurring subscription. Check out `SKProductViewController` docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstoreproductviewcontroller/). Also recommend reading StoreKit guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html)

Comment: It's from iOS 11 with production IAP, please watch What's New in StoreKit https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/303/